# How to select the whole sheet in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I am using `xlwings`. I want to copy the whole `wb1.sheets(1)` and paste to `wb.sheets(1)` `A4` cell. Currently I have to set a very large cell `Z100000`. Is there any generic way to select the whole sheet rather than the unsafe region `A1:Z10000`?

```
import xlwings as xw
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx'
app=xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
wb1 = app.books.open(path)
wb = app.books.add()
wb1.sheets(1).range('A1:Z10000').copy(wb.sheets(1).range('A4'))
```

I want to know how to select：

1. The entire sheet i.e. Ctrl+A,
2. The used part. Suppose wb1 write the area `A1:F5`. May be we can assume wb1 always begins from `A1`.

Comment: Your need is to select entirely the sheets, or only the used part 
?

Comment: @Glauco actually I want to know both, pls see my update

Comment: Accepting answers is a smooth way to verify that one of the provided answers solves the problem. 
Has the answer solved the problem? if yes please accept it.

Comment: @mouwsy I will definitely accept your answer, I still left one question, could you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to find the the range filled with contents, not necessarily all cells on the sheet. If so, simply use [used_range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=used_range#xlwings.Sheet.used_range):

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(path)
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.used_range.select()
```

But if you really want to select the entire sheet (including all empty cells), which sounds rather unusal, use the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(path)
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.activate()
ws.api.Cells.Select()
```

Comment: thx, for `ws.used_range.select()`, is it possible to know the maximal row/column used?

Comment: and the syntax will be ws1.used_range.select().copy(wb.sheets(1).range('A4'))? It seems no copy function.

Comment: Please read the docs. And it would be `ws1.used_range.copy(wb.sheets(1).range('A4'))`.

Comment: thx, but I found `used_range.copy` may ignore the range with chart?

Comment: Yes, `used_range` ignores charts, pictures, and shapes. If you want to ask how to include them in the range, that's something for a new question.

Comment: thx, asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72844469/how-to-select-the-whole-sheet-in-xlwings-especially-include-all-charts